# Updating to Ruby 1.9.2 on Windows

Tags: windows, ruby

I have a Windows 7 64-bit computer with ruby 1.8.7 installed and want to update to 1.9.2. I installed 1.8.7 by downlooading and runing  [Ruby Installer](http://rubyinstaller.org/) . How do I update to ruby 1.9.2 so ruby 1.9.2 replaces 1.8.7 so that there are not two versions of ruby on my computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- rename c:\ruby
- Install latest version of ruby
- Overwrite C:\ruby\lib\ruby\gems
- 'gem update' (at your command line) to update your gems.

Answer (score 1):

Use https://github.com/vertiginous/pik/ to manage multiple versions of ruby on windows.

Comment: I don't want multiple versions of ruby just one. I want ruby 1.9.2 to replace 1.8.7 so I only have 1.9.2 on my windows machine.

Comment: Having multiple versions isn't required with pik, it just makes it easier to manage ruby versions (even if you just have one version installed). If you don't want to use pik, uninstall 1.8.7 and use http://rubyinstaller.org/ to install 1.9.2

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.